# Save Data to Array Variable in For Loop

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop

I need to find the earliest & latest dates for certain table entries.

A link to [a diagram of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUKz8.jpg).

The premise is that every time an entry has a desired pairing of "Name" and "Desc" I want to grab the date, and then find the earliest & latest dates associated with that pairing.

My solution was to create an Array variable, save all the dates in integer form (Long) and then print the Min and Max functions of that Array.

The first date the loop encounters isn't saving to the array, so the first element is always "0" and there's always a date missing.

```vb
Sub Test2()
'Search a table for specied subject / entry description, to find the earliest & latest corresponding dates

'Empty array variable for later use
    Dim TheDates() As Long

    Dim Xds As String
    Dim Xnm As String
    Dim NameR As Range
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim Dum As Integer

'Placeholder values assigned to Xds and Xnm for testing
    Xds = "Charlie @ £8.50"
    Xnm = "Beatriz"

'Counter set to 0
    Counter = 0
    ReDim TheDates(Counter)

'Run through each entry in the table
    For Each NameR In Range("Draft[Name]")
'Check if an entry contains the desired pairing of Name & Desc ( Xnm & Xds )
        If NameR.Value = Xnm And NameR.Offset(0, 8).Value = Xds Then
'In cases they match follow the below procedure
    'Set the array size of 'TheDates' to current counter value
    'Set the 'counter'th element in the array to the entry's date
    'Increment the Counter ready for the next case
            ReDim TheDates(Counter)
            TheDates(Counter) = CDbl(NameR.Offset(0, 3))
            Counter = Counter + 1
        'When an entry does not match the desired pairing it is ignored
            Else
        End If
    Next

'For testing purpose I am printing the end results to the page
    Range("N13") = WorksheetFunction.Min(TheDates)
    Range("N14") = WorksheetFunction.Max(TheDates)

'I am also printing the array in its entirey to analyse
    For Dum = 0 To Counter - 1
    Range("Q13").Offset(Dum, 0) = TheDates(Dum)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Within the loop: `ReDim TheDates(Counter)` - this effectively erases the array if you don't use `Preserve`. But it's much better practice to size the array once, outside the loop.

Comment: (!) Oh thank you, plugged in Preserve and fixed it right off. That's what I'd missed.

I would have liked to set the size outside the loop BUT I have no way of knowing prior to running the loop how many entries it will find, and if I overshoot the array size I'll be left with a bunch of zeroes interfering with the MIN function

Comment: You could `ReDim Preserve` *after* the loop then, using the value of `Counter`. Make the array sufficiently big before the loop, then after the loop resize it down to just the populated values.

Comment: Hmm valid point, thanks, will implement that now, appreciate your help

Comment: Upload your image to Stack Overflow imgur, not regular imgur